# How to Poll for a specific number of messages using Amazon SQS Springn cloud annotation @SqsListener

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud-aws

Need: to poll/listen 10 messages at a time(Specific count not based on polling time)
Existing code base using spring cloud aws messaging  polls based on time by default. 
now required to poll based on the counts of messages.

Looking for a annotation based configuration similar approach to the below code

```
@SqsListener(value = "xxx-sqs",deletionPolicy = ON_SUCCESS)
public void auditProcessor(String json) throws IOException {
    log.info("*********** Inside Listner***********");
    log.info("JSON Data "+json);
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of messages requested from SQS can be [configured in SimpleMessageListenerContainerFactory](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.4.1/reference/html/index.html#the-simplemessagelistenercontainerfactory).

That being said SQS works in a way that even if you ask for 10 messages you have no guarantee you will get 10 even if there are more messages in the queue. You can only be sure that you will not get more than 10.

Comment: this link returns 404 not found.